# NFT is not displaying on opensea under goerli testnet

Tags: nft, opensea

My bought NFT is not displaying on opensea under goerli testnet. Does anybody have an idea what is the issue?
I am using testnets.opensea.io

Answer (score 5):

Since OpenSea uses Rinkeby, I made an NFT explorer for Goerli to solve this issue.

https://goerli.pixxiti.com

There's no trading or bidding, but you can explore over 2 million NFTs (ERC721 and ERC1155) live on Goerli today.

Comment: Hey there! Mind sharing how you made that website? Are you crawling the network and saving the addresses of ERC721 or ERC1155 contracts?

Answer (score 4):

Based on the OpenSea documentation `testnets.opensea.io` works only on the Rinkeby Blockchain.

Source: https://docs.opensea.io/reference/rinkeby-api-overview